# Basic SVN Commiting Process

Tags: svn

Im new to SVN and have a quick questions regarding commits. I have my local machine that I work on that commits to my dev server. After I check on dev I login to my production box and update the modified files to make it live.

Right now I have some committed files on my dev box. I want to make more changes to those specific files on my local machine and commit them again to update. Do I do anything differently? Will the new commits just write over as I think it will? Sorry for such a basic question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it will overwrite the existing files in the SVN. Basically a big advantage with SVN (and all version control systems) is that you have a full history of changes that you made.

So if you end up with a critical issue in your latest set of changes you can revert your code to the previous version before those changes were made.

If you have multiple developers working on the project then don't forget to do an update before you start making your changes otherwise you might end up with conflicts if you've both been editing the same file.